# Updating a wordpress post without changing its status by API

Tags: wordpress, api

When I publish a post to WordPress I can (but do not have to) set a status. If I do it the post is published with the correct status. If not, it is published as published. I do not have problem with it.

The problem I have is when I want to update it. When I do it I do not know the status of the already published post. It could have changed since I published it. But when I re-publish it (without unpublishing it first and setting any status), it is automatically published by WP.

Is there any way to tell WP not to touch the status of the post I am updating and keep it as it is?

Or is there some setting with some "default status", which is used, whenever I use their API to publish the post?

Comment: Can you run an api call before saving to get the post status before hand then use that value when you send your update?

Comment: It crossed my mind, but no. There is a raise condition and I cannot rely that the status is the same as it was even few seconds ago. I want to be 100% sure, that the status is unchanged.

Comment: Good point... do you have access to the WP install, to make code changes if needed, or is that totally out of your hands?

Comment: I believe we can find a way to do some code changes if it needed.